# Resetting screen setup in XP (msgina.dll failed to load)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have an measurement system connected to a computer running Windows XP SP3 (since the hardware does not support newer versions of Windows). The basic setup is a primary monitor used for Windows and a secondary monitor output connected to the measurement system. Today I had to disconnect the primary monitor for a while and when I reconnected the monitor, Windows had made the second monitor output the primary one. Since the second monitor output is connected to the measurement system I had to connect using UltraVNC to switch back the primary. UltraVNC did not like that and disconnected so I missed the 15 second delay of the confirmation dialog before reverting to the old settings. Eventually I got the right monitor as primary and rebooted the computer to settle everything.

Directly after reboot the computer displays the following dialog box:

[image: msgina.dll failed to load]

> User Interface Failure
>
> The Logon User Interface DLL msgina.dll failed to load.
>
> Contact your system administrator to replace the DLL, or restore the original DLL.
>
> [Restart]

Connecting to the c$ share, I have compared the files C:\Windows\system32\msgina.dll and C:\Windows\system32\dllcache\msgina.dll and they are identical. Just to make sure the HDD doesn't have a bad sector or something I renamed the system32\msgina.dll file and was going to make a new copy from dllcache to system32. But Windows had already made the copy, presumably from dllcache (the files are identical).

Rebooting the computer I still get the same error message. I have also tried Last Known Good Configuration and Safe Mode with the same results. I have also tried a complete power off/power on cycle.

I suspect that the monitor information somehow got screwed up and that is the true cause of the msgina.dll loading error. I have disconnected the measurement system so only one monitor is connected. I even tried disconnecting the monitor so all monitor outputs were disconnected, when connecting using UltraVNC I got the same error message.

- Is there some way to reset all monitor information in Windows XP?
- Are there some other possible missing files which could cause the msgina.dll loading error?

The computer is a HP Z620 with a Nvidia Quadro FX 3800 graphics card, running Windows XP SP3. The msgina.dll has not been replaced by a custom implementation, the login screen and logo are the Windows defaults).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got some time to investigate the problem further. Most suggestions for fixing the msgina.dll error is to replace the msgina.dll with the one from C:\Windows\system32\dllcache, but that didn't solve anything for me.

Booting from a [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/), I ran the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool on msgina.dll which reported:

```
ODBC32.DLL Error processing file. This file may not be a valid 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module.
```

I replaced the corrupted file with the ODBC32.DLL from the dllcache folder and ran Dependency Walker once more - no errors. Now the computer boots Windows just fine.